# forge.facebook.authorize with read and write permission for IOS 6 sdk

Tags: ios6, trigger.io

am using trigger.io to build my IOS app. i need facebook login with some read and write permission from user but IOS 6 sdk giving error
message = "FBSession: Publish or manage permissions are not permited to to be requested with read permissions.";
type = "UNEXPECTED_FAILURE";
};
i have tried 2 things:
1) at the start login user with just read permission and after that when i need write permissions then i try tu authorize user again with forge.facebook.authorize with only write permissions 
2) when i need write permissions i have logout user 1st using forge.facebook.logout and authorize again
but non of then work.

Answer (score 0):

So issue was publish_stream permission was replace by publish_actions permission and facebook android sdk and javascript sdk was working with the old one butt IOS sdk was not so replacing just name solved my problem. remember i am using this approach "at the start login user with just read permission and after that when i need write permissions then i try tu authorize user again with forge.facebook.authorize with only write permissions"